# Container is being run as HTTP locally but HTTPS on ECS (Terraform)

Tags: flask, terraform, amazon-ecs, terraform-aws-modules

So I've got this super basic terraform app to spin up a basic Flask app via ECS.

I want everything to be HTTP while I get some testing going.

The code I used is from here.

https://github.com/Finleap/tf-ecs-fargate-tmpl

However, I'm using my own container/ECR. The issue is that when the task runs, the container is listening on HTTPS, not HTTP.

Remote:

```
2022-06-09 23:55:50,897  * Running on all addresses (0.0.0.0)
2022-06-09 23:55:50,897 * Running on all addresses (0.0.0.0)
2022-06-09T19:55:50.897-04:00   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
2022-06-09T19:55:50.897-04:00   * Running on https://127.0.0.1:5000
2022-06-09T19:55:50.897-04:00   * Running on https://10.0.9.254:5000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

Local:

```
* Debug mode: on
2022-06-10 00:00:01,086  * Running on all addresses (0.0.0.0)
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000
 * Running on http://172.17.0.2:5000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

For the life of me, I can't figure out what's going on. Any advice?

Comment: I know this isn't an answer, but could you just use https locally w/ a self-signed cert?

Comment: Yea but then I'd have to modify the terraform code to forward to https, which is doable, but I'd also like an answer to figure out what's going on too.

Comment: I just tested having the ALB point to HTTPS and that fixed it. Which is unsatisfying :(

Comment: My guess is it is related to a difference in the environment variables in your ECS task definition, versus your local environment.